# Bamboo remove exclude changesets when creating a plan branch

Tags: git, bamboo

First we have activated:

**Create a plan branch when:**

> When new branch in repository is created

I have an automated plan who update and commit the new version number on the `master` branch.

So I have added an ***exclude changesets*** on my master branch to only trigger a build when a commit includes: `automated push from ci`

But I need to always trigger a build on the other branches.

How I can **remove for all branches** the ***exclude changesets*** and **for the futures branches**?